# How to auto login to a website in a webview using various methods

Tags: javascript, android, cookies, webview

Hi stackoverflow community,
i had been trying to create an app with a webview in it,that auto login's the user into the website.once the user just opens it i had been using java script to auto fill the username and password column  using the below code.Website-[website](http://www.bvrit.edu.in)

```
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:var username =document.getElementById('txtId1').value='" + username + "';");
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:var userpassword =document.getElementById('txtPwd1').value='" + password + "';");
```

I had used the below code to click the login button

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                        "l=document.getElementById('imgBtn1');" +
                        "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');" +
                        "e.initEvent('click',true,true);" +
                        "l.dispatchEvent(e);" +
                        "})()"
        );
```

But since me being a newbie here i coudn't figure out why  the code just works sometimes and doesn't work some other times.Also please tell me why my present code is not able to log me in.The fields gets filled but the button dosn't get pressed but when the username or password is wrong it shows me invalid username or password i.e it gets pressed when the credentials are wrong.when credentials are right the fields gets filled but it dosn't log me in if i manually press the login button it logs me in.What i think is there is a problem to override the new URL using automatic java script press.Please tell me how to fix this one.There are many other issues i am facing using this.
my complete main activity is-[Main Activity](http://pastebin.com/SvEEpiPV)

I also realised that this is not an effective way to login to a website using java script.So i was trying to figure out any other method to login to a webview using cookies since i have the login credentials or by using any POST methods to send the required data values.to login to the website.So can any of you help me to select and implement a best method to login to a webview.Sorry if i written anything wrong.

Thankyou.

Comment: Your WebView will save cookies by default, so if the website is one that you own, authorizing through a cookie should work just fine.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe thanks for your help NoChin but it's our instutes website and i don't own it..